# Need to track down a copy of version 1.5 of Google Analytics for iOS

Tags: ios, google-analytics

I'm adding Google Analytics to my armv6/armv7 project and I get a linker error when trying to build for an armv6 device:

```
libGoogleAnalytics.a, file is universal but does not contain a(n) armv6 slice for architecture armv6
```

Turns out that the version of Google Analytics I'm using (1.5.1) dropped support for armv6. Can anyone direct me to a copy of version 1.5, which I presume will work in my project?

Google don't appear to keep archived versions around, and I couldn't dig up a copy looking around the web.

Thanks.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a search engine or link referral site; Google and Bing both specialize in that sort of thing. Voting to close as "off topic".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got it by guessing the url.

http://dl.google.com/gaformobileapps/GoogleAnalyticsiOS_1.5.tar.gz

Comment: Many thanks Eduardo.  Yeah, I'd figured it out too shortly after posting my question.  And I'm pleased to say everything works very well with this version of the library.